# How to find out the URL to which a process is trying to connect to?

Tags: windows-7, networking, download, process, network-monitoring

I have a program that is downloading some files from the Internet transparently (I don't know from where the files are downloading). I want to find out the URL of those files that are currently downloading.  Is that possible?

I use Windows 7.

Comment: This is extremely vague...  What is your operating system, what is the protocol? If Linux, you could try `tcpdump`, if Windows, you could try `wireshark`; if this is over SSL, you will have a difficult time determining the destination through simple packet inspection.

Comment: @Matt Clark I added the operating system details on the question, but I have no idea about the protocol though.

Comment: _ahem_.. `wireshark`.

Comment: Do you have a *process* (running program) that's actively downloading files?  Or do you have a program that *already downloaded* files and you want to know where they came from?  As written, your question seems to be asking both.

Comment: @Twisty, the first case, a process that's actively downloading files.

Comment: @MattClark Wireshark (or more generally, a packet sniffer) can't tell you the URL that a file is being downloaded from unless you capture *the first few packets* of the HTTP connection. OP says *those files that are currently downloading* which seems to me to indicate that there is a *download in progress;* that's a far tougher nut to crack.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling correct, the sniffer would have to be running when the download is initiated - i gave the only answers I could given OPs vague post.

Comment: @alimammadi123 Are you interested in knowing the exact **URL** used to initiate the download of each file, or the Internet **hostname** from which the file(s) are being downloaded?  My answer provides the latter but not the former.

Comment: @Twisty, Thank you for your answer, I want to know the exact URL, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tools that can tell you what hosts a process is connected to.  `Netstat` is one, Process Explorer is another.

But to find the exact URL?  The only way to do that is to use a packet sniffer and watch for HTTP GET messages.  The message header will have the URL of the resource being requested.